# generic throw giving Expected an object to be thrown lint error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, eslint, throw

Below throw code giving lint error **Expected an object to be thrown no-throw-literal**

```
throw { code : 403, message : myMessage };
```

if i try **throw new Error**, i am not getting eslint but it gives [Object Object] in the response.

```
throw new Error({ code : 403, message : myMessage });
```

Could someone tell me how to fix **Expected an object to be thrown** error ? without removing eslint config/rules

Comment: `throw new Error(myMessage);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Syntax

Comment: @ankr but i want to send two properties, Code too

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
 throw Object.assign(
   new Error(myMessage),
   { code: 402 }
);
```

Throw a regular error and extend it with custom fields.

---

You could also write a reusable error class for that:

```
  class CodeError extends Error {
   constructor(message, code) {
    super(message);
    this.code = code;
   }
 }

 throw new CodeError(myMessage, 404);
```

That way, you can distinguish the errors easily on catching:

```
  } catch(error) {
    if(error instanceof CodeError) {
      console.log(error.code);
    } else {
      //...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 21):

Another simple workaround is store on variable and throw.

```
const errorMessage =  { code : 403, message : myMessage };
throw errorMessage;
```

Comment: Webstorm doesn't like this: Local variable 'errorMessage' is redundant.

Comment: This error will not have a stack trace. If that's what you want, it is better to disable the lint rule rather than building a workaround to trick it.